# How can I receive signals with Mono.Posix on Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-core, mono-posix

When creating a UnixSignal object I get a System.EntryPointNotFoundException with the the Message:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'Mono_Unix_UnixSignal_install' in DLL 'MonoPosixHelper'.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        UnixSignal sigint = new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGINT);
        UnixSignal sigterm = new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGTERM);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for SIGINT or SIGTERM");
        UnixSignal.WaitAny(new[] { sigint, sigterm });

        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
    }
```

I am using Nuget library Mono.Posix.NETStandard, on Windows 10, VS 2017. The error is the same with either a .net Core 2.0.0 app or .net Framework v4.6.2 app. Ultimately I plan to run my app on Mono in Linux but need to do the development in Windows.

Comment: This just isn't going to work on windows. And how would it? There is no such thing as SIGTERM signal in windows for example.

Comment: @Evk Windows does support it albeit poorly, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx

Comment: If you are on .net core - I'd suggest to use Console.CancelKeyPress event. Despite its name, it handles those signals (on unix) just fine, and works as you expect on windows too. I'd also avoid mono for any new project (unless of course it's unity/mobile).

Comment: if your target is Linux+mono, just develop and test with Linux+mono, as it's the most logical way to avoid problems